# How to calculate hamming distance of number having binary format

Tags: mysql, sql, binary, formatting

I tried below code for calculating hamming distance of two decimal numbers, and got the expected result:

```
 SELECT BIT_COUNT('16056695327593349911' ^ '13147651924325057303') AS hamming_distance ;    

output : 8
```

But when I tried converting above two decimal numbers to binary, it gives me a wrong result:

I tried below query:

```
 SELECT BIT_COUNT(CAST(CONV('16056695327593349911',10,2) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER) ^ CAST(CONV('13147651924325057303',10,2) AS UNSIGNED INTEGER)) AS hamming_distance ; 

 output: 0
```

I want to calculate hamming distance of two binary numbers.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as *"binary number"* or *"decimal number"*. A [number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number) is a quantity. Ten items are ten items, no matter if you write their number as `10` (base 10), `1010` (base 2), `'X'` (roman numerals) or `'ten`' (English). The number is still the same, only the way we write it differs.

The [bitwise `XOR` operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/bit-functions.html#operator_bitwise-xor) doesn't care how do you write the numbers, it internally represents them in binary and applies the `XOR` operation on their bits.

This is how the numbers you posted (`16056695327593349911` and `13147651924325057303`) look in binary:

```
1101111011010100110101110101010000010011111000000100000000000000
1011011001110101110101111100010000010011111000000100000000000000
 ^^ ^   ^ ^    ^        ^  ^
```

I marked under them the `8` positions where they differ in their binary representation. This number (`8`) is the Hamming distance you compute.

The value of `16056695327593349911 ^ 13147651924325057303` is `7539307869670211584` and its binary representation is below:

```
0110100010100001000000001001000000000000000000000000000000000000
 ^^ ^   ^ ^    ^        ^  ^
```

Please note that it has `1` on the positions marked on the first figure (where the input numbers have different bits in their binary representation) and `0` where the corresponding bits of the input numbers are equal.

---

The [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) of two strings is the number of positions where they differ. If you use the bitwise XOR operator to find the differences then you are technically computing the Hamming distance of the **binary representations** of the two **input numbers**.